# javascript, quiz score wont work

Tags: javascript

the code doesnt give different scores for right and wrong answers, i need it to give the total score for the questions; even if you put wrong answers it says you've still got 3/3

```
<html>
        <head> 
        <title>
            00000
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //variables
            var q1 = parseInt(prompt("What data type is a number? " + " A:Boolean      
    B:     Integer  C: String"));
            var q2 = parseInt(prompt(" What operator means not equal to? " + " A:< 
            B: = =  C: !="));
        var q3 = parseInt(prompt(" Which function is used to square root?" + "A:
            math.sqrt  B: math.pi  C: math.pow"));
            var score1 = 0;
            var score2 = 0;
            var score3 = 0;


            //calculate score
            if (q1 = "B") 
                score1 = 1
                else if (q1 = "A" || "C")
                    score1 = 0

            if (q2 = "C") 
                score2 = 1
                else if (q1 = "A" || "B")
                    score2 = 0

            if (q3 = "A") 
                score3 = 1 
                else if (q1 = "B" || "C")
                    score3 = 0

            totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3;

            //output
            alert("Total score = " + totalScore + "/3");            

        </script>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `=` is not a comparison operator and usage of `||` is incorrect.

Comment: my lecture slides say that || means 'or', and i know == means equal to but the program doesnt work with ==

Comment: to elaborate on what @ZongZhengLi is saying. `==` is used for comparison and `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: @NicoleDenny .. you would want to check `if ((q1 == 'A') || (q1 == 'C'))`

Comment: if ((q1 == 'A') || (q1 == 'C')) <-- just put this into the else if statements and now the program doesnt run

Answer (score 2):

You are using assignment operators instead of comparison in your evals.

```
if (q1 === "B")
   score1 = 1
else
   score1 = 0
```

First eval will always return true if "B" can be assigned to q1 when using = 
Use == or === to evaluate if q1 is the same as "B".

Comment: just added that code and it does work but now gives 0/3 for all answers

Comment: It has to do with how you are collecting the user input. Parsing a char to int will never return "A" "B" or "C". Better to use a text field and button to collect an answer, then pass the answer through a switch statement, and assign the score that way. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify your code greatly with a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript). Something like,

```js
var q1 = "A";
var q2 = "B";
var q3 = "C";
var score1 = (q1 === "B") ? 1 : 0;
var score2 = (q2 === "C") ? 1 : 0;
var score3 = (q3 === "A") ? 1 : 0;
var totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3;
alert("Total score = " + totalScore + "/3");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're expecting a string response on your `prompt`, you shouldn't be running a `parseInt()` on the response as you'll get `NaN` any time a non-integer is entered thus making your further tests useless.

Second, as already mentioned, to do a comparison, you should use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

Last, there are plenty of ways to greatly simplify this script e.g. the below:

```js
// Store the responses and answers in their own arrays
var responses = [
      prompt("What data type is a number? " + " A: Boolean B: Integer C: String "),
      prompt(" What operator means not equal to? " + " A: <  B: == C: != "),
      prompt(" Which function is used to square root?" + "A: math.sqrt B: math.pi C: math.pow ")
    ],
    answers = ['B','C','A'], // Store the correct answers in order
    score = 0; // Start off the score at zero.

// Match each response with it's respective answer
// and add +1 to the score if they match...
// Also, make sure the input is a string so toUpperCase() works (in case someone answers in lowercase)
for(x in responses) {   
  score = (typeof responses[x] == 'string' && responses[x].toUpperCase() == answers[x]) ? score+1 : score;
}

// Show score
alert('You scored ' + score + '/3');
```

Comment: thankyou, i just ran this and it still says 0/3 even with the right answers